# Why is this image unable to be viewed properly as a <ul> background?

Tags: css

[What I want to achieve.](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/navbarw.png)

The white background image cannot be inserted into the `ul` navbar properly. The drop shadow and inner glow effect of the white background cannot be seen after insertion.

[What is seen after Insertion. (jpg background image)](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/wis1.png)

[What is seen after Insertion. (png background image)](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/pngqqq.png)

Html and CSS below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title> Foodstant Delivery </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylo.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

    <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="OP"><a  href="Orders.html">Your Order</a></li>
                <li class="MP"><a  href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="CUP"><a  href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="JP"><a  href="Jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></li>
                <li class="TCP"><a  href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>

</body> 

</html>
```

CSS :

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#navbar {
    background:url('images/navbarbg1.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 150px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

#navbar ul li {     
        float:left;
        padding:0 60px 0 0; 
        list-style-type:disc;
        }

#navbar ul li.OP {
        list-style-image:url('images/order.png');
}   

#navbar ul li.MP {
        list-style-image:url('images/menulogo2.png');
}

#navbar ul li.CUP {
        list-style-image:url('images/contact.png');
}

#navbar ul li.JP {
        list-style-image:url('images/Pen.png');
}

#navbar ul li.TCP {
        list-style-image:url('images/pin.png');
}
```

UPDATE: I managed to get it to work somewhat, but under mysterious circumstances. Sizes are abit off, and it doesn't cover the first icon. 
[Image](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/a111.png)

```
#navbar {
    background:url('images/navbarw1.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 150px;


    background-position: 50% 50%;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

"#navbar" doesn't have any dimensions set, and it's containing a `ul` that contains floated elements, which likely are not "contained", which probably means "#navbar" is not showing up.  As you're using a background that doesn't repeat in the height dimension, it is advisable to have that dimension set up anyway.

Edit:  I also agree with pcridesagain (but maybe not exactly) in that the reason for [this](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/a111.png) is that you're still using the li's as list items.   Making them "display:block;",  displaying the images as background (non-repeating) images positioned left and center (vertically), give enough line-height to the lis and left padding is what I've often used as well.  Also with this arrangement, you have more fidelity as to how you want to position the backgrounds, which you don't using list item images. However I can see why you might want to use them as list items images, as sometimes doing all that can be a bit painful *because* you have all that fidelity.

Comment: Hmm I added the height in - `#navbar {
 background:url('images/navbarw1.png');
 position: absolute;
 top: 300px;
 left: 150px;
 height: 3000px;
 
 font-size: 26px;
 font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
 
 
}` . It worked, but the white bg image is stuck somewhere below the navbar text.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ul overflow to hidden

```
ul{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try out, instead of selecting the div #navbar with the background image, select the `ul` itself with `#navbar ul{...}`. The reason why its not covering the first icon is because you'll need to set the `list-style-type` to `none`. Get rid of the `list-style-type` and use a `backgroundiimage` + `padding-left` on the `li` to create the icon.